# Does order of independent kernel-module insertion at system startup matter?

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver, kernel-module

This is the background for this question -
I've got some problems with Huawei sometime back as it was being detected as a usb storage device but not as a data card. I came across this thread while I was searching for the solution https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-source-2.6.20/+bug/105545
I remember solving it by following instruction given in this thread and changing the order of insertion of usb-storage and usb-serial modules in the start-up script as follows(assuming every insertion of a module is explicitly written in the start-up script)

```
insmod usbserial.ko 
insmod option.ko 
insmod usb-storage.ko
```

After doing the above, it got detected as a data card successfully. So does this order matter when these modules are independent?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency can be checked by the command `modinfo <module_name>.ko | grep depend`. However, using `modprobe` command is much better than `insmod`, you don't need to worry about dependency by using `modprobe`.